# R - Repeating function to multiple "anchor points"

Tags: r, statistics, repeat

Sorry if this is a poorly phrased question, I'm confused on the best way to organize my data in R. Here is the data frame:

```
 Experiment Treatment              Inhibitor      pAKT Loading Control
          1      None                   DMSO  7075.426       16051.376
          1 Carbachol                   DMSO 18368.962       14826.962
          1 Carbachol          10-8 M BYL179 14949.184       10911.477
          1 Carbachol          10-7 M BYL179 11972.477       10993.305
          1 Carbachol          10-6 M BYL179 14874.841       12610.841
          1 Carbachol          10-8 M Cal101 11433.598       12305.891
          1 Carbachol          10-7 M Cal101 10297.719       13175.012
          1 Carbachol          10-6 M Cal101  2835.891       11609.598
          1 Carbachol 10-8 M BYL179 + Cal101  8749.134       12024.012
          1 Carbachol 10-7 M BYL179 + Cal101  4490.841       13088.598
          1 Carbachol 10-6 M BYL179 + Cal101   598.012       10929.134
          2      None                   DMSO 11904.225       30755.104
          2 Carbachol                   DMSO 27637.518       27536.912
          2 Carbachol          10-8 M BYL179 13970.619       24052.326
          2 Carbachol          10-7 M BYL179  7567.326       21889.154
          2 Carbachol          10-6 M BYL179  8421.326       13446.033
          2 Carbachol          10-8 M Cal101  4754.497        7333.912
          2 Carbachol          10-7 M Cal101  3614.497        3566.376
          2 Carbachol          10-6 M Cal101  1426.598        1331.326
          2 Carbachol 10-8 M BYL179 + Cal101  7401.175        6010.447
          2 Carbachol 10-7 M BYL179 + Cal101  3159.740        5280.154
          2 Carbachol 10-6 M BYL179 + Cal101  2114.376        9793.347
          3      None                   DMSO  4528.690       20969.347
          3 Carbachol                   DMSO 27218.104       23433.912
          3 Carbachol          10-8 M BYL179 12507.619       21712.033
          3 Carbachol          10-7 M BYL179  4673.790       13934.154
          3 Carbachol          10-6 M BYL179  6699.033        8018.497
          3 Carbachol          10-8 M Cal101 10108.861       17364.861
          3 Carbachol          10-7 M Cal101 10728.326       25307.447
          3 Carbachol          10-6 M Cal101  7418.083       20826.012
          3 Carbachol 10-8 M BYL179 + Cal101 17169.104       23850.255
          3 Carbachol 10-7 M BYL179 + Cal101 14890.811       36585.368
          3 Carbachol 10-6 M BYL179 + Cal101  5889.497       19609.033
          4      None                   DMSO  5029.841       14217.083
          4       EGF                   DMSO 17963.719       16883.255
          4       EGF          10-8 M BYL179 18191.719       15706.719
          4       EGF          10-7 M BYL179 17430.719       16327.891
          4       EGF          10-6 M BYL179 15350.305       14828.134
          4       EGF          10-8 M Cal101 15847.891       14122.598
          4       EGF          10-7 M Cal101 17678.426       16659.719
          4       EGF          10-6 M Cal101 14236.477       15380.012
          4       EGF 10-8 M BYL179 + Cal101 14281.891       15367.012
          4       EGF 10-7 M BYL179 + Cal101 13918.012       13796.062
          4       EGF 10-6 M BYL179 + Cal101  4702.062       12578.012
          5      None                   DMSO 14192.004       40446.196
          5       EGF                   DMSO 43425.246       46626.125
          5       EGF          10-8 M BYL179 43465.004       45206.832
          5       EGF          10-7 M BYL179 34098.882       36853.175
          5       EGF          10-6 M BYL179 33415.882       37637.539
          5       EGF          10-8 M Cal101 32413.175       31047.054
          5       EGF          10-7 M Cal101 32359.882       35967.004
          5       EGF          10-6 M Cal101 27089.761       33929.125
          5       EGF 10-8 M BYL179 + Cal101 30945.882       29804.882
          5       EGF 10-7 M BYL179 + Cal101 32511.711       37228.832
          5       EGF 10-6 M BYL179 + Cal101 10176.832       36218.024
          6      None                   DMSO 17417.004       47193.439
          6       EGF                   DMSO 49204.075       55932.489
          6       EGF          10-8 M BYL179 45682.832       52486.125
          6       EGF          10-7 M BYL179 37131.711       41015.004
          6       EGF          10-6 M BYL179 32859.761       33375.933
          6       EGF          10-8 M Cal101 39127.711       33037.004
          6       EGF          10-7 M Cal101 35535.589       33514.539
          6       EGF          10-6 M Cal101 25455.175       28547.882
          6       EGF 10-8 M BYL179 + Cal101 21374.589       24441.296
          6       EGF 10-7 M BYL179 + Cal101 19590.125       22268.660
          6       EGF 10-6 M BYL179 + Cal101  5347.782       21943.317
```

I want to create a new column titled "Correction Factor", generated by dividing the Loading Control value for a specific entry by the entry with Treatment "None" and Inhibitor "DMSO" for that experiment. So for example the first entry for Experiment 1 would be 16051.376/16051.376 = 1, the second would be 14826.962/16051.376 = 0.9237, the third would be 10911.477/16051.376 = 0.6798, and so on. For Experiment 2 I would divide by the Experiment 2 None + DMSO entry, 30755.104. How do I repeat this action for every experiment?

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly follow, but if since R data frames are essentially column vectors, couldn't you populate a new column vector with the current index of loading control/the last index to change in experiment and iterate through?

Comment: Awesome, it worked! I was wondering, is there a way to do this without any looping?

Answer (score 2):

While this can certainly be done in base R, Hadley Wickham's tools provide a nice way to do this (split data frame by some criterion, apply a transformation on the subsets, and stick them back together - "split-apply-combine" for short).

(These are *untested* but I think they should work ...)

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) ## load dplyr *second!*
```

### plyr (Hadleyverse/tidyverse 1)

```
ddply(my_data,"Experiment",
     mutate,
         Correction.Factor=Loading.Control/
           Loading.Control[Treatment=="None" & Inhibitor=="DMSO"])
```

### dplyr (Hadleyverse/tidyverse 2)

```
my_data %>% group_by(Experiment) %>%
     mutate(Correction.Factor=Loading.Control/
           Loading.Control[Treatment=="None" & Inhibitor=="DMSO"])
```

Another (base-R-friendly) approach would be to subset out the baseline (None/DMSO) cases, retain only the Experiment and Loading.Control columns (but renaming the latter),  and then `merge` the result back with the original data set - then all you have to do is divide one column by another ...

Comment: I tried running this, but it says I have a "non-numeric argument to binary operator" - I think it's because of the / but I don't know how to fix it... am I missing anything here?

Also, just for future reference how would I do this in base R?